# Unable to extract user_id from google API

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a working google-app-engine server written in Python. All HTTP requests are handled perfectly, except for when I try to register a google-user to the server, when I call the users.get_current_user() I get None in the return value.

Is there anything I need to enable on my google developer console?

- The same app can register to another server with the exact same API (written by other team).

Thanks in advance,

Comment: do your users authenticate with google accounts? else its by design

Comment: They are authenticated. As I said they can authenticate with other servers (which use the exact same function call)